# calculate angle with three CGpoint

Tags: objective-c, ios, rotation, cgpoint

I have three CGpoint and I would like calculate the angle.

I drawn a little schema :

[image]

I tried with this code :

```
CGPoint u ;
        u.x = 0;
        u.y = - middleRectY;

        CGPoint v ;
        v.x = x1 -  middelRectX;
        v.y = y1 - middleRectY;

        // formule = u.v / ( ||u|| * ||v||)

        double cosa = (double)((u.x * v.x + u.y * v.y)) / sqrt(u.x * u.x + u.y * u.y) * sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);

        // angle en degré

        double angle = (180.0 / M_PI) * acos(cosa);

        // Signe de l'angle

        int sign = (u.x * v.y - u.y * v.x) > 0 ? 1 : -1;

        rectYellow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle*sign);
```

But my function return "nan" :/

Thx :)

Comment: What returns NaN exactly? Which function?

Comment: When I test with NSLog(@"%f",angle) , the console return "nan".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem !

It just a probleme of parenthesis :

```
double cosa = ((u.x * v.x) + (u.y * v.y)) / (sqrt((u.x * u.x) + (u.y * u.y)) * sqrt((v.x * v.x) + (v.y * v.y)));
```

I don't understand why ?
Because the parentheses aren't necessary for multiplication ...

Comment: It might have been because of the excessive parenthesis in `((u.x * v.x + u.y * v.y))`, precedence of operators doesn't seem like the issue.

Comment: @VivienCormier - your original was of the form A / B * C, your revision is of the form A / (B * C) - and those two are of course not the same (unless C is 1!)